# Can't edit Info.plist (read/write permission) in XCODE 7

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to solve the issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http/32560433#32560433).

I found a solution: edit my info.plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I tried to edit every way I could think of (Textedit, xml edit, open as source code, etc.). I even tried to do it manually with raw values, but every time I try to save it, it freezes.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

my info Plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MY APP</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon.png</string>
        <string>Icon_76x76.png</string>
        <string>Icon_152x152.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.myapp.app</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2.6.3</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2.6.3</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
<-- Here I was trying to copy paste -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What freezes? Xcode? Your editor? The running app?

Comment: yes which ever way i try that freeze, if Xcode then Xcode.

Comment: plz let me know why this happens .. even i can not add 1st key with dict properly ...xcode freeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end you can add like this.. this resolves you.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```